# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources', \build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 while android Build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.1

I am trying to compile & build my project using Android studio latest version which have many dependent modules as below:

- FacebookSDK
- OneMobi
- VkOpenAuthActivity
- Android Support lib V4 - 23.3.0
- Android Google Maps (Latest)
- App (Project Module)

**Android Plugin Ver:** - 2.1.2
**Gradle Build Ver:** - 2.10

During build all modules are compile & build successfully except App module. I have also checked by compiling by every module independently where its showing error in APP module.

Please let me know where i am missing in build file or i have to looking my .xml files.

Please refer below detail error log:

```
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"titleTextStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":422}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"subtitleTextStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":422}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"divider\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":422}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"background\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":422}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"backgroundSplit\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":422}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"navigationMode\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"displayOptions\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"title\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"subtitle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"icon\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"logo\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"backgroundStacked\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"customNavigationLayout\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"homeLayout\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"progressBarStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"indeterminateProgressStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"progressBarPadding\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"itemPadding\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":463}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"initialActivityCount\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":466}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"expandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":466}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"preserveIconSpacing\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":469}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"iconifiedByDefault\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":476}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"queryHint\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":476}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"windowActionBar\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"windowNoTitle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"windowActionBarOverlay\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"windowActionModeOverlay\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"windowMinWidthMajor\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"windowMinWidthMinor\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionBarTabStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionBarTabBarStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionBarTabTextStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionOverflowButtonStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionBarStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionBarSplitStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionBarWidgetTheme\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionBarSize\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionBarDivider\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionBarItemBackground\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionMenuTextAppearance\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionMenuTextColor\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionModeStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionModeCloseButtonStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionModeBackground\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionModeSplitBackground\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionModeCloseDrawable\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionModeShareDrawable\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionModePopupWindowStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"textAppearanceLargePopupMenu\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionDropDownStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"dropdownListPreferredItemHeight\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"spinnerDropDownItemStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"homeAsUpIndicator\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"actionButtonStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"selectableItemBackground\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"dividerVertical\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"activityChooserViewStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"popupMenuStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"textAppearanceSearchResultTitle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"textColorSearchUrl\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"listPreferredItemHeightSmall\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"listPreferredItemPaddingLeft\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"listPreferredItemPaddingRight\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"dropDownListViewStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"listPopupWindowStyle\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"textAppearanceListItemSmall\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"buttonStyleSmall\" has already been defined","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\app\\Project Workspace\\appExploreStudion\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":489}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

FYI I am also giving all the build.gradle file content here below:

Main application - **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**`App.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.visa.asiapacific"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':vKOpenAuthActivity')
    compile project(':onemobi_4_prod')
    compile files('libs/AF-Android-SDK-v3.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/AutoNavi_Android_Location_V1.0.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/AutoNavi_Android_Map_3d_2.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/AutoNavi_Android_Services_3d_2.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/localytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/Sina_Weibo_sdkcore.jar')
    compile files('libs/Tencent_Wechat_sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/Tencent_Weibo_sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/Tencent_Weibo_sdk_component.jar')
    compile files('libs/VK_commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
}
```

**`facebookSDK.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.1.2.jar')
}
```

**`onemobi.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/OneMobi.jar')
}
```

**`VkOpenAuthActivity.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
}
```

I am trying to resolve this form days, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jalp

Comment: Resolve all the issues by myself. There are several things to be taken care off:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case -

> Multiple library projects declaring the same custom attribute name
>   causes conflict.
>
> Using different build tool & compiling versions also causes the
>   conflict here as i used build-tool ver - 24 and compiling my app using
>   ver - 23.0.3. So i make it to all
>   (compileSdkVerison/buildToosVersion/targetSdkVersion) as - 24. Also
>   make sure you use the same version support & google libs if you using
>   for maps, backward compatibility etc.

Things that needs to be taken care of while resolving such issues, find below checklist:

- Check your compileSdkVersion, buildSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion dependencies, its should't conflict with one another. If you are using compileSdk - 24 then make sure you used the build version also similar to 24.x.x. In most of the cases your compileSdkVersion should match with targetSdkVersion.
- If you are using multiple custom libraries/modules then make sure your custom resource should not be conflicted while compiling your project as whole app.
- While creating your custom styles/themes make sure you define attributes with your custom specific prefix like - For my lib project cacheLib you define your attribute as `<attr name="cacheLib_background" format="reference" />`so that this attributes are not conflicted with the existing attributes provided by the android SDK.